# How to use the result of the query within a function to execute UPDATE

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm very new to SQL and I'm currently using Postgres to execute a function. Essentially, I want the function to 1) first perform a query, 2) depending on the condition, update the specified field, and 3) return the result.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_overdue()
RETURNS TABLE (
    overdue boolean,
    due_date DATE
)
$$
BEGIN
SELECT overdue, due_date FROM booking;
IF NOW()::DATE > due_date::date then
-- I want to execute and return the following the query result: UPDATE booking SET overdue = true WHERE (the result of the above query) 
END IF;
end$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the logic well, you can do this in a single query:

```
update booking
set overdue = true
where due_date < current_date
returning *;
```